# Как перевести str в int или float?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Хочу посчитать в Pandas кое-какие значения. Загружаю файл, а там все значения отображаются как object.

Попытался перевести с помощью:

```
df = df.col.astype('float')
```

И далее ошибка:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '4097575,00000'
```

А когда пытаюсь перевести в `int` также выдает ошибку значения:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4097575,00000'
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Похоже при сохранении CSV файла в качестве десятичного разделителя использовалась запятая, вместо точки.

Воспользуйтесь параметром `pd.read_csv(..., decimal=",")`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(..., sep=";", decimal=",")
```

Comment: Спасибо, все сработало!

Answer (score 0):

Все логично, astype('float') обрабатывает только валидные значения, в вашем случае "," должна быть заменена на ".", например вот так

```
df[col].apply(lambda x: str(x).replace(",", ".")).astype('float')
```

Comment: спасибо за совет, но почему у меня не получается сделать это методом ```replace```

Comment: Выше неплохой вариант предложили